# Unable to create Mimi Corext or Loki alert on Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, grafana-loki, grafana-alerts

Under Alertings under warning rules, it displays that there are no compatible datasources for Mimir or Loki alert. Is there a method that this could be resolved from the server side. Where is this occuring from ? Thanks in advance.

I have tried to check if the data source is proper and it has been setup right (The Loki data source). The logs are being received by Grafana just fine.